# CSS Columns Layout (flexbox, float, columns)

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float, css-multicolumn-layout

I am struggling to achieve the following layout as shown in the screenshot:

[image: desired outcome]

This is part of a filters section in a page, that opens up after clicking the button for that filter that triggers it.

The part that has bugged me, is the columns layout.

The current mark-up is like so:

```
<div class="dropdown-wrapper open">
  <div class="dropdown-inner-wrap open">
    <div class="bs-searchbox"></div>

    <div class="inner open" role="listbox" style="max-height: 320px; overflow-y: auto;">
      <ul id="klfilter_location" class="dropdown-menu inner">
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-1">
          <legend role="option" class="opt">
            <label for="region-north">
              <span class="text">
                <span class="main-data-region">North</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox" hidden="" class="hidden" id="region-north" value="north">
            </label>
          </legend>
          <ul class="grouped-options group-1">
            <li class="optgroup-north">
              <a role="option" class="opt">
                <label for="8">
                  <span class="check-mark"></span>
                  <span class="text">
                    <span class="main-data">Option A1
                      <span class="count">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" hidden="" class="hidden" id="8" name="Location[]" value="8">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-north">
              <a role="option" class="opt">
                <label for="9">
                  <span class="check-mark"></span>
                  <span class="text">
                    <span class="main-data">Option A2
                      <span class="count">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" id="9" name="Location[]" value="9">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-2">
          <legend role="option" class="opt">
            <label for="region-west">
              <span class="text">
                <span class="main-data-region">West</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" id="region-west" value="west">
            </label>
          </legend>
          
          <ul class="grouped-options group-2">
            <li class="optgroup-west">
              <a role="option" class="opt">
                <label for="10">
                  <span class="check-mark"></span>
                  <span class="text">
                    <span class="main-data">Option B1
                      <span class="count">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" id="10" name="Location[]" value="10">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-west">
              <a role="option" class="opt">
                <label for="11">
                  <span class="check-mark"></span>
                  <span class="text">
                    <span class="main-data">Option B2
                      <span class="count">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" id="11" name="Location[]" value="11">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="grid-item klfilter-btn-toolbar">
      <button>Clear</button>
      <button>Go</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

- The number of the "group uls" and their items is unspecified and changeable.
- It's okay to display a vertical scrollbar inside the container - but horizontal scrollbar is undesirable.

**Initially I tried with flexbox.**
When set in `flex-direction: row`, if any group ul is too high, then there is a big empty vertical space among the other group.

[Codepen Flexbox flow row](https://codepen.io/jmbeat/pen/jOrxQMX)

If I use `flex-direction: column` , I need to specify some height for the flex container. But then I might end up with more columns, exceed the available width and have horizontal scroll.

[Codepen Flexbox flow column](https://codepen.io/jmbeat/pen/Pozexje)

**I tried with CSS columns:**
I tried many combinations and have various issues which is hard to remember and describe exactly right now. One big issue though, was that I couldn't "keep together" the group `ul`s - or create an alignment at the top and have groups start from there.

[Codepen CSS Columns](https://codepen.io/jmbeat/pen/XWKqyYd)
*Which actually it looks ok now

**I tried with float**
Well, the problem is that with the uncertain height of each group, the floating elements can go/stuck anywhere and the whole layout will be messy.

**I tried with css grid**
I have far less experience with grid - so I am not sure if I tried everything that is possible, but still I just managed to create a 3x3 grid layout - and when one group ul is too high I got big space between the rows.

Any ideas - suggestions on how to achieve this?

Ideally, the elements should be able to be aligned like here (similar to the first image - but displays better a long left group):

[image: ideal layout]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `column-count`, delete the min-height of the container and to avoid column breaks within subgroups use `page-break-inside: avoid;` on them.

```css
.inner.open {
  column-count: 3;
}

.optgroup {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

#klfilter_location {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-wrapper open">
  <div class="dropdown-inner-wrap open">
    <div class="bs-searchbox"></div>

    <div class="inner open" role="listbox" overflow-y: auto; ">
      <ul id="klfilter_location " class="dropdown-menu inner ">
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-1 ">
          <legend role="option " class="opt ">
            <label for="region-north ">
              <span class="text ">
                <span class="main-data-region ">North</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox " hidden=" " class="hidden " id="region-north " value="north ">
            </label>
          </legend>
          <ul class="grouped-options group-1 ">
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="8 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " hidden=" " class="hidden " id="8 " name="Location[] " value="8 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="9 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden" id="9 " name="Location[] " value="9 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-2 ">
          <legend role="option " class="opt ">
            <label for="region-west ">
              <span class="text ">
                <span class="main-data-region ">West</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="region-west " value="west ">
            </label>
          </legend>

          <ul class="grouped-options group-2 ">
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="10 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="10 " name="Location[] " value="10 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="11 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="11 " name="Location[] " value="11 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
<ul class="grouped-options group-1 ">
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="8 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " hidden=" " class="hidden " id="8 " name="Location[] " value="8 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="9 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="9 " name="Location[] " value="9 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-2 ">
          <legend role="option " class="opt ">
            <label for="region-west ">
              <span class="text ">
                <span class="main-data-region ">West</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="region-west " value="west ">
            </label>
          </legend>

          <ul class="grouped-options group-2 ">
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="10 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="10 " name="Location[] " value="10 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="11 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="11 " name="Location[] " value="11 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
<ul class="grouped-options group-1 ">
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="8 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " hidden=" " class="hidden " id="8 " name="Location[] " value="8 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="9 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="9 " name="Location[] " value="9 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-2 ">
          <legend role="option " class="opt ">
            <label for="region-west ">
              <span class="text ">
                <span class="main-data-region ">West</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="region-west " value="west ">
            </label>
          </legend>

          <ul class="grouped-options group-2 ">
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="10 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="10 " name="Location[] " value="10 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="11 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="11 " name="Location[] " value="11 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
<ul class="grouped-options group-1 ">
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="8 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " hidden=" " class="hidden " id="8 " name="Location[] " value="8 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="9 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="9 " name="Location[] " value="9 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-2 ">
          <legend role="option " class="opt ">
            <label for="region-west ">
              <span class="text ">
                <span class="main-data-region ">West</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="region-west " value="west ">
            </label>
          </legend>

       
<ul class="grouped-options group-1 ">
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="8 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " hidden=" " class="hidden " id="8 " name="Location[] " value="8 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="9 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="9 " name="Location[] " value="9 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-2 ">
          <legend role="option " class="opt ">
            <label for="region-west ">
              <span class="text ">
                <span class="main-data-region ">West</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="region-west " value="west ">
            </label>
          </legend>

          <ul class="grouped-options group-2 ">
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="10 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="10 " name="Location[] " value="10 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="11 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="11 " name="Location[] " value="11 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
<ul class="grouped-options group-1 ">
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="8 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " hidden=" " class="hidden " id="8 " name="Location[] " value="8 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="9 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="9 " name="Location[] " value="9 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-2 ">
          <legend role="option " class="opt ">
            <label for="region-west ">
              <span class="text ">
                <span class="main-data-region ">West</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="region-west " value="west ">
            </label>
          </legend>

          <ul class="grouped-options group-2 ">
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="10 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="10 " name="Location[] " value="10 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="11 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="11 " name="Location[] " value="11 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
<ul class="grouped-options group-1 ">
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="8 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " hidden=" " class="hidden " id="8 " name="Location[] " value="8 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="9 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="9 " name="Location[] " value="9 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-2 ">
          <legend role="option " class="opt ">
            <label for="region-west ">
              <span class="text ">
                <span class="main-data-region ">West</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="region-west " value="west ">
            </label>
          </legend>

          <ul class="grouped-options group-2 ">
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="10 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="10 " name="Location[] " value="10 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="11 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="11 " name="Location[] " value="11 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
<ul class="grouped-options group-1 ">
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="8 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " hidden=" " class="hidden " id="8 " name="Location[] " value="8 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-north ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="9 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option A2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="9 " name="Location[] " value="9 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-header optgroup optgroup-2 ">
          <legend role="option " class="opt ">
            <label for="region-west ">
              <span class="text ">
                <span class="main-data-region ">West</span>
              </span>
              <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="region-west " value="west ">
            </label>
          </legend>

          <ul class="grouped-options group-2 ">
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="10 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B1
                      <span class="count ">(1)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="10 " name="Location[] " value="10 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="optgroup-west ">
              <a role="option " class="opt ">
                <label for="11 ">
                  <span class="check-mark "></span>
                  <span class="text ">
                    <span class="main-data ">Option B2
                      <span class="count ">(6)</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox " class="hidden " id="11 " name="Location[] " value="11 ">
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

    <div class="grid-item klfilter-btn-toolbar ">
      <button>Clear</button>
      <button>Go</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Johanes ... I was about to give columns another chance, as in a codepen (https://codepen.io/jmbeat/pen/XWKqyYd) I just created it seems to work. Actually, while was working with the browser inspector - I was able to achieve it on my project with css columns - but then, everytime I was adding the required css on my stylesheet and had the page refreshed, it was not working 100% right ... I am gonna try your solution and will get back with the outcome.

Comment: I reached somewhere I have kept the height of the container ( it was needed anyway) - I am sure I had tried the same before... it's rather complex to provide the final solution... but overall it's close to the codepen with the css columns. Thanks for your help - much appreciated.